# CSS Background doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I try to add background to a table cell but doesn't work.

```
.price-table td.left-up {
    background: url("img/left-up.png") no-repeat;
    width: 181px;
    height: 118px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="price-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-up">
        sdst
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that img location is correct? Do you see an `img` folder at the same level with the page you placed this code in? Do you see the `left-up.png` file in that folder?

Comment: What is your tree structure? The path name must be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified a *relative* path name here - which is probably why the image isn't loading. Remember that relative paths work relative to the CSS file, not to the page. For example:

```
/site
  -page.htm
  /css
    -site.css
  /img
    -left-up.png
```

If this were your folder structure you would need:

```
background: url("../img/left-up.png") no-repeat;
```

This is because the image is one level up **relative to the css file**. Hope that helps you figure out the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

Use a pure link to your image eg. `http://yoursite.com/img/left-up.png`